# siunitx: specifying custom command as input-symbol

Tags: symbols, siunitx

This is a follow up from [siunitx uses math mode for symbols - workaround needed when using different fonts for math and text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46301/siunitx-uses-math-mode-for-symbols-workaround-needed-when-using-different-font/46340#comment97589_46340).

The problem has been solved thanks to David, however there is a problem remaining with tables that are generated by `esttab` for Stata. Esttab enters asterisks by a newly defined `\sym` command, i.e. `\sym{*}`. This is not necessary since I have redefined `\sym` to plain text, but esttab does not offer an option to omit the `\sym` command.

The problem is that siunitx does not recognise `\sym` as an input-symbol and the result are overfull hboxes, as the MWE below illustrates. My question is how to specify `\sym{*}`, `\sym{**}` and `\sym{***}` as input symbols for siunitx as I would like to avoid hacking the esttab plugin (btw, the problem is not pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX specific).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\overfullrule=5pt

% For Tables created by estout
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{#1} % for symbols in Table
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{ detect-mode, 
          group-digits            = false ,
          input-signs             = ,
          input-symbols           = ()[]-+* , % specifying \sym here does not work
          input-open-uncertainty  = ,
          input-close-uncertainty = ,
          table-align-text-post   = false 
        }

\def\xxx#1{%
  \bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string#1%
  \uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text\string#1}}%
  \mathcode\expandafter`\string#1"8000 }
\def\textsymbols{\xxx[\xxx]\xxx(\xxx)\xxx*}

\begin{document}

{\textsymbols
\begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{
    l @{\extracolsep\fill} *{2}{S[table-format=4.6]} @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\emph{Age}}  \\[0.5ex]
18--24 &   [-1360.228]*  &  -1371.941\sym{*}  \\
       &       (6.915)\sym{**} &    (-7.953)**      \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{$#1$}} % for symbols in Table
```

works for that example, as the symbols are always at the right edge of the column otherwise I'd need to look at the weekend to see what siuintx does with its symbol list.

Comment: That is certainly much better than before. So your solution only works when the `\sym` is the last element of a column? That would not be a problem as the significance values are always after a number. But is there a reason why you put the symbol into math mode (because thanks to your solution it is converted to text later).

Comment: maths mode, not really, just habit:-) `\rlap` makes its content have zero width and stick out on the right so `\rlap{a}b` makes the `a` overprint the `b`, but at the right hand edge it just sticks into the column space

Answer (score 1):

If you have issues with stars overlapping with the next column as I did, rewrite David's line of code to read

`\newcommand{\sym}[1]{{#1}} % for symbols in Table`

and it'll put the stars in the superscript and pushing the next column on the right over to make space.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at hand.