# Character substitution: combine \llap{(} and \llap{-} to \llap{(-}

Tags: symbols, siunitx, characters

This is a follow up to question [siunitx: specifying custom command as input-symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47418/siunitx-specifying-custom-command-as-input-symbol) . The idea is that `(`,`)` and `-` are wrapped into `\llap` or `\rlap` so that they do not take any space when a table is set via `siunitx`.

The problem is that it does not work when I have `(-` in one column: because it is substituted with `\llap{(}\llap{-}`, causing the left bracket and the minus to be overlapping. Obviously this would need to become `\llap{(-}`. But I don't know how to achieve this in the current framework developed by David Carlisle as shown in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}}

\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        detect-mode,
        group-digits            = false,
        input-symbols           = ( ) [ ] - +,
        table-align-text-post   = false,
        input-signs             = ,
        }   

% Character substitution that prints brackets and the minus symbol in text mode. Thanks to David Carlisle
\def\yyy{%
  \bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string-%
  \uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\llap{\textendash}\relax}}}%
  \mathcode\expandafter`\string-"8000 }

\def\xxxl#1{%
\bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string#1%
\uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\noexpand\llap{\string#1}}}}%
\mathcode\expandafter`\string#1"8000 }

\def\xxxr#1{%
\bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string#1%
\uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\noexpand\rlap{\string#1}}}}%
\mathcode\expandafter`\string#1"8000 }

\def\textsymbols{\xxxl[\xxxr]\xxxl(\xxxr)\yyy}


 \begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\textsymbols
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{S[table-format=1.2,table-column-width=20mm]}}
Variable 1 & 1.85\sym{***} & 0.92\sym{***} & 1.11\sym{***} \\
           & (-0.34)       & (0.24)        & (0.14)        \\
Variable 2 & 0.07\sym{***} & 0.07\sym{***} & 0.07\sym{***} \\
           & (-0.01)       & (0.02)        & (0.01)        \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `(` lookahead and handle a following `-`

(again with corrected code and image)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}}

\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        detect-mode,
        group-digits            = false,
        input-symbols           = ( ) [ ] - +,
        table-align-text-post   = false,
        input-signs             = ,
        }   

% Character substitution that prints brackets and the minus symbol in text mode. Thanks to David Carlisle

\def\yyy{%
  \bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string-%
  \uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\llap{\textendash}\relax}}}%
  \mathcode\expandafter`\string-"8000 }

\makeatletter

\def\xxxl#1{%
\bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string#1%
\uppercase{\egroup\edef~##1{##1\edef\noexpand\thisxxx{\string#1}\futurelet\noexpand\tmp\noexpand\zzz}}%
\mathcode\expandafter`\string#1"8000 }


\def\zzzx#1#2{\def\tmp{#2}%
\ifx\tmp\zzzm
\text{\llap{\thisxxx$\mathchar"2200$}}%
\else
#1{#2}%
\fi}


\def\zzzm{-}
\def\zzz{\ifx\tmp\ensuremath
           \expandafter\zzzx
          \else
\text{\llap{\thisxxx}}%
          \fi}

%\noexpand\@ifnextchar\noexpand-\noexpand\xxxlm{\noexpand\text{\noexpand\llap{\string#1}
\makeatother

\def\xxxr#1{%
\bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string#1%
\uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\noexpand\rlap{\string#1}}}}%
\mathcode\expandafter`\string#1"8000 }

\def\textsymbols{\xxxl[\xxxr]\xxxl(\xxxr)\yyy}


 \begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\textsymbols
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{S[table-format=1.2,table-column-width=20mm]}}
Variable 1 & 1.85\sym{***} & 0.92\sym{***} & 1.11\sym{***} \\
           & (-0.34)       & (0.24)        & (0.14)        \\
Variable 2 & 0.07\sym{***} & 0.07\sym{***} & 0.07\sym{***} \\
           & (-0.01)       & (0.02)        & (0.01)        \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant, that works! Two points: Could you elaborate a bit on what the code does? I get lost from `futurelet`onwards. And within my framework I don't use the mathminus because that's the one from Eulermath. I used `textendash` here for simplification, but normally I use `textminus` from `textcomp` (works fine with your solution).

Comment: maybe later :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know you only said 'maybe' but you must admit that it *is* 'later'... I was trying to understand your code in relation to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167266/minionpro-siunitx-and-some-character-substitution-bad-mathchar-32768. I can't get your solution here to work there anyway, but I was initially interested in why you'd used a different solution for left and right (whereas the OP there is trying a symmetrical solution).

Comment: @cfr the question here (as far as I recall thinking it about at the time) was specifically about `(-` so I only handled that case not `)`

Comment: Ah, OK. That actually makes a lot more sense of what you were doing. [Not that I understand it but I can sort of get the general idea.] Thanks.

Comment: @cfr I just had look at the other qn but I don't have the font package (nor the incentive to install it:-) so I can't see why it generates the mathchar error.

Comment: @cfr I've closed the question you linked because it was essentially a duplicate. The trickery above does not work with `-` when `amsmath` is loaded which `MinionPro` does by default. David already provided a solution for that.