# MinionPro, siunitx and some character substitution: Bad mathchar (32768)

Tags: math-mode, fonts, siunitx, minionpro

I've been using a solution that allows me to:

1. Use proportional figures in text and tabular figures in tables;
2. Force `siunitx` to set "symbols", e.g. `( ) -` in the text-font instead of the math-font, developed by David Carlisle ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46301/siunitx-uses-math-mode-for-symbols-workaround-needed-when-using-different-font/46340#comment97589_46340), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47418/siunitx-specifying-custom-command-as-input-symbol) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83344/character-substitution-combine-llap-and-llap-to-llap)).

I've been using the code for a few years, but I can't get the MWE below to work with `MinionPro`. It results in the error message: `Bad mathchar (32768)`. When loading `MinionPro` with `onlytext` (or using another font), the substitution trickery works fine. The problem is the left bracket, i.e. `\xxxl(`, the right bracket works fine.

The frustrating thing is that I use this code in my large style files and it works fine - but I want to create a minimal style file, and I just can't find the mistake.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}

\usepackage{MinionPro}% other fonts work fine as well as using 'onlytext'

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{%
    input-symbols           = ( ) [ ] - +,
}

\def\xxxl#1{%
\bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string#1%
\uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\noexpand\llap{\string#1}}}}%
\mathcode\expandafter`\string#1"8000 }

\def\xxxr#1{%
\bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string#1%
\uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\noexpand\rlap{\string#1}}}}%
\mathcode\expandafter`\string#1"8000 }

\def\textsymbols{\xxxl(\xxxr)}% the left bracket ( causes the problem

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\figureversion{tabular,tab}
\textsymbols
\begin{tabular}{S S S}
(0.096) & (0.012)& (0.108) \\
 0.136  &  0.021 &  0.024
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This can be closed as duplicate. I forgot that `MinionPro` loads `amsmath`, hence I need to include the `amsmath` correction from David's answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46340/11984.