# Access minus symbol of postscript font in textmode

Tags: characters, text-mode

Do postscript fonts such as `libertine` (from the `libertine-legacy` package) or mathpazo have a minus sign that can be accessed when in text mode? What I am trying to do is substitute the normal dash with a minus symbol, following this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46301/siunitx-uses-math-mode-for-symbols-workaround-needed-when-using-different-font) from David Carlisle.

His solution works perfectly when using open type fonts as most of them have a minus character that can be easily accessed:

```
\def\yyy{%
  \bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string-%
  \uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\char"2212\relax}}}%
  \mathcode\expandafter`\string-"8000 }
```

However, my attempts to do something similar with `pdfLaTeX` and Libertine or Pagella have been futile. Using a symbol like hyphen (`\textendash`) works perfectly:

```
\def\yyy{%
  \bgroup\uccode`\~\expandafter`\string-%
  \uppercase{\egroup\edef~{\noexpand\text{\llap{\textendash}\relax}}}%
  \mathcode\expandafter`\string-"8000 }
```

But is not exactly what I want. How can I access the minus symbol of that font? Or, if that is not possible, is it possible to resize the hyphen to "fake" a minus symbol?

**Edit**: egreg provided the solution below. Embedded into my framework the code is:

```
\def\yyy{% Thanks to egreg
  \begingroup\uccode`~=`-
  \uppercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathbin{\text{\llap{\textminus}}}}
  \mathcode`-="8000 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The en dash is in position `"15` in the T1 encoding:

```
\begingroup\uccode`~=`-
  \uppercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathbin{\text{\char"15 }}}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`-="8000 }
```

Alternatively, there's `\textminus` in the TS1 encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begingroup\uccode`~=`-
  \uppercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathbin{\text{\textminus}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`-="8000 }

\begin{document}
$-$
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I need a minus, not the en dash...?

Comment: @Jörg There's no minus sign in the T1 encoding.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. But I think there is no need to load `amsmath` here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost. I do not understand that is intended here. Even zooming at huge font size, I cannot see any difference between the customized  $-$ with \textminus nor the simple -- in text mode using this MWE.

Comment: @Jörg You need at least `amstext` for `\text`.