# siunitx rounding in table with parentheses

Tags: tables, formatting, siunitx

I'm trying to create a standard regression table with standard errors in parentheses below the coefficients, while using `siunitx` to align the numbers on the decimal point, and to round the numbers.

I use the option `input-symbols=()` to make `siunitx` ignore the parentheses, which works fine for alignment, but the numbers in parentheses are not rounded:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[input-symbols=(),round-mode=figures,round-precision=1]}} 
\hline
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} \\
\hline
X & 0.0131     & 0.00265{***} \\
  & (0.000731) & (0.000547)   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If I instead put the parentheses in curly brackets, the rounding works, but the left paranthesis ends up left aligned in the table cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[round-mode=figures,round-precision=1]}} 
\hline
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} \\
\hline
X & 0.0131         & 0.00265{***}   \\
  & {(}0.000731{)} & {(}0.000547{)} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get rounding to work with parantheses? I have the latest version of `siunitx`, 2.4j.

Comment: Tinkering a bit more, I've found that adding the options `table-align-text-pre=false,table-align-text-post=false,table-space-text-pre=(,table-space-text-post=)` and wrapping all parentheses in curly brackets gives me the output I want.

Still, it would be very nice if this was possible without the curly brackets and the extra options.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this answer to a question I asked some time ago: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46186/11984

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following appears to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        detect-mode,
        tight-spacing           = true,
        group-digits            = false,
        input-signs             = ,
        input-symbols           = ,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        table-align-text-pre    = false,
        round-mode              = figures,
        round-precision         = 1,
        table-space-text-pre    = (,
        table-space-text-post   = ),
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S}} 
\hline
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} \\
\hline
X & 0.0131     & 0.00265*** \\
  & (0.000731) & (0.000547)   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly! Just to clarify for others who might have this problem, the key options for solving this problem are `input-open-uncertainty  =, input-close-uncertainty = , table-align-text-pre = false`.

Comment: I think the key option is to omit `( )` from the input-symbols, because you define parenthesis in this case with the `table-space-text-pre`and `table-space-text-post` option

Comment: Actually, it works even excluding the `table-space-pre=(`and `table-space-post=)`-commands. I think they only help with getting the column width right.

Answer (score 1):

From the `siunitx` manual:

> A common means to display negative numbers in ﬁnancial situations is
>   to place them in brackets. This can be carried out automatically using
>   the `bracket-negative-numbers` option.

this may offer a very clean "work-around".